# What triggers the firing of the "onLoad" event?

Tags: jquery

If I want to change a div background image using jQuery, does it trigger the `$(window)`'s onLoad function?

Comment: What do you mean? Does changing a css attribute with jQuery trigger a call to window.onLoad, no. See there for information about window.onLoad : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload

Answer (score 1):

No, the `load` event for `window` (which is the same as the one for `document`) is triggered when the document has been loaded and then loaded all initial content.

Making a style change that causes something to load doesn't retrigger the event.

Answer (score 0):

onLoad executes a JavaScript immediately after a page has been loaded.

> The onload event occurs when an object has been loaded. onload is most
>   often used within the  element to execute a script once a web
>   page has completely loaded all content (including images, script
>   files, CSS files, etc.).

```
In JavaScript Syntax:
    object.onload="SomeJavaScriptCode"
```

onload is Supported by the Following HTML Tags:

```
<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script>, <style>
```

If you are into jQuery refer the code below. write the code in the $(document).ready() section. It's a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  //code to change the background
});
```

Which is equivalent to calling:

```
$(function() {
 // Handler for .ready() called.
 //code to change the background
});
```

[read more](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Hope this will solve your problem. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks.

Comment: So, to make a changing background, do I have to make the background an img#ID?

Comment: no. Just change the css of the background using .css() function in jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: But how do I change it every X seconds? I can change it once with the css() function..

Comment: window.setInterval(function(){
  /// call your function here to change the css
}, 1000);

This code will do the trick for you

Comment: Ok, so when I write this code:
  var iRnd = -1;
  var iPrev = -1;
  var aImages = new Array();
  aImages[0] = 'url(../images/bg_01.png)';
  aImages[1] = 'url(../images/bg_01.png)';
  aImages[2] = 'url(../images/bg_01.png)';
  aImages[3] = 'url(../images/bg_01.png)';
  $(document).ready(function() {
   window.setInterval(function() {
   while (iRnd == iPrev)
    iRnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*aImages.length);
   $("#slideshow").css('background-image', aImages[iRnd]);
   iPrev = iRnd;
    }, 2000);
   });
the first image is defined by default, and when the 2 seconds pass, it just goes blank